# Best way to store column data as row MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some data which columns is dynamic and the number of column data can increase/decrease at any time. So i am planning to store them in row wise instead of the column format.

I have the master table of columns placed and its indicate what data type the columns is using. I am drawing the master table below for your reference

```
CID     Name          Type
1      Speed         Double
2      Input1        Bool
3      Message       String
.......
.......
```

Now i have thought of two way to store this dynamic column data
First way is

```
CID      Data_bool       Data_String      Data_Double
1        NULL            NULL             12
2        True            NULL             NULL
3        NULL            test             NULL
1        NULL            NULL             5
1        NULL            NULL             15
```

Second way was to have one generalized varchar column and store each value as string over there so it looks like

```
CID      Datas
1        12
2        True
3        test
1        5
1        15
```

If you look at the database normalization point of view then second ways seems to be good. But i think it can create problem in data retrieval. Because i want to filter the data like "Speed > 10". So if i go second way (Where i store all value as string) i think the expression will take more time to evalute
And if i go first way for the expression then first I need to determine the columns against which i need to evalute the expression. Ex. for the expression Speed > 10, first i have to check Speed is of which data type (string, bool etc) and then again execute the expression of "data_double > 10"

Both have their own drawbacks. Can someone point out that which way will give me less headache in future. Remember this table will grow in millions of records on later stage.

I appreciate your view and time here. thank you.

Comment: After thinking all the possibilities, i have decided to go with my first way. i know its not normalized but i think if i go for normalization then the performance will be big issue. I am ok (with heavy heart) with the HD space rather than optimizing all the queries for faster performance. This table is heart of all the computed reports.

Answer (score 2):

I' m not shure how you are accessing the data, maybe [SQL_Variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  may be a option for you in combination with [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx).

```
Declare @a table(id int, cont sql_variant)
insert into @a select 1,'test'
insert into @a select 1,Cast('20130101' as DateTime)
insert into @a select 1,Cast('20130201' as Datetime)
insert into @a select 1,Cast(1 as Bit)
insert into @a select 1,Cast(0 as Bit)
Select * from
(
Select *  from @a
where SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(cont,'BaseType')='datetime'
) x
Where cont>Cast('20130101' as DateTime)
```

Comment: I am new to this SQL_Variant type. Looks promising but once my table size gets larger do you think "SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(cont,'BaseType')='datetime'" will take more time? Apart from that it really looks cool

Comment: A can't give a solid answer about performance. Since `(sql_variant_property([cont],'BaseType'))` is non deterministic, you can't create an index on a computed colum, so I'd expect performance issues with many data. Since in my case the rows are prefiltered by other conditions and SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY is used to resolve fieldmappings I did not have performance issues in mmy case of use.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use a one table for each data type you're interested in. Each of these tables would have just two fields. An int-type PK and a corresponding-type column to store data. In the master table, you could just have an FK of int-type that links to one of the specific type tables and another field of tinyint type that decides which child table the FK belongs to.

**Master Table**

ID        int        PK

ValueID   int        Not Null

Type      tinyint    Not Null

**Child Table(s)**

ID        int        PK

Value     string     Not Null

The ValueID is FK from Child table to Master table. Similar child tables can be created for other types.

Comment: dont you think that this will be make query hard? First i will need to find which table to make join and then apply the join. I think the dynamic SQL will also come into play here.

Comment: You can create a single view, `LEFT JOIN`ing all your child tables with the master table. This will create one column for each child table in the view, just like the first table structure you posted in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn’t answer your question of which of these two options is better but I hope it will be useful anyway.

I wouldn’t go with any of these two options. I’d rather try to see if I can fit these into columns (it’s not uncommon to have tables with 50 or 100 and even more columns) and/or different tables.

I’d recommend you install TFS or Dynamics CRM and see how they store data. They built the application code so that it’s able to add/delete columns in database and they have a set of tables that keeps track of this meta data.

If there are really that much different values than I’d try with XML data types.

Comment: you are right. But my problem here is i dont know how many columns data i will get around. I am following incremental model and later on i dont want to recreate the table again and again to accomodate extra columns. XML is also way but i am afraid then retrieving/filtering data will be a big problem

Answer (score 0):

I have seen and worked with this type of problem on a number of occasions, particularly where the application has to allow for user configuration of field names and data types.

The solution in these cases was Key-Value (ie. 2-column) tables that used varchars for all keys [obviously] but also for all values.

This is a very powerful solution that belies its simplicity!

Although this is the most simple and extensible option it may not be the most performant. Having a Key-Value table for each data type can help but is a little more difficult to programme for. Alternatively, include a Type field and columns for each data type in the same table (but is not my favourite as this does waste space).

The database based applications I worked on, that used the varchar Value approach, performed with no noticeable slowness; however, they really only operated using simple key-based lookups. Your situation may differ, particularly if you do more complex queries on your data. Stating the obvious, but, applying primary keys to the Key fields will improve lookup speed.

**Additional notes:**

Apologies for recycling what I have read on various forums but I have not used variant types in my own databases. I have read that:

1) In SQL Server 2005 onwards, using a variant type instead of a varchar type - in this case, for the Value column - will result in faster operation,

2) they don’t work with LIKE in WHERE clauses,

3) OLE DB and ODBC providers automatically convert variants to nvarchar(4000).

Comment: What about the combining my first and second way. As per mentioned by "dotNET" below, i have partitioned my first way table to 3 sub table (each for different type) and storing value in 2 column which is ID and value. And left joining all the table which will get me result like first way of mine. I think it looks good

Comment: The combined approach, including @dotNET's LEFT JOIN view idea, should suit your needs fine; I would go with this. Without testing it, I would expect the performance to be no problem for all but huge datasets.